# Trying to find older SF short story/novella about a split telepathic human race

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Pre-1990s short story (maybe novella) where half the human race is transported to a separate world (maybe Alpha Centauri?) with advanced technology, and half the human race remains on Earth and develops telepathy. Neither side is aware what happened to the other half. The two meet up again after several centuries.